# Create a Flow that sums up and updates fields

Tags: visual-workflow, recordtriggeredflow

Flow newbie here! I want to create a triggered flow(create/update) from obj ''QUOTE'' that sums up the total Price and Discounted Total Price from **ALL ACTIVE=Y** Quotes and populates the Total Price and Discounted Total Price in obj Project.

QUOTE and PROJECT are related through ''Project Name''. Status ACTIVE is a checkbox.[image: Schema]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please [edit] your question to include specific detail of your object model. You say these objects are related though "Project Name". Is this some arbitrary string, or is there actually a more formal relationship using a Master Detail or Lookup field? If the latter, have you considered using rollup summary fields or a dynamic rollup solution such as [Apex Rollup](https://github.com/jamessimone/apex-rollup) or [DLRS](https://github.com/SFDO-Community/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)?